# Changes to a webpage through javascript not appearing in WebView. Is there a way to force the WebView to redraw its content?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Here are the steps involved:

- Load a local html file with WebView.loadUrl().
- This local html file has several javascript methods that modify the page.  Such as adding an image, or changing the text size.
- Call one of these methods using WebView.loadUrl("javascript:somefunction()");

This works just fine.  The changes show up nicely.

However, if the page is being scrolled while this is called, something really weird happens.  The javascript is called and by looking at logging, the DOM changes and everything went as expected on that level.  However, the WebView doesn't show the update.  If you then do something to force it to redraw itself, like rotate the device or call one of the javascript methods again (but not scrolling this time) the previous changes finally appear.

So there seems to be some weird bug where changes to the page by javascript are not updated in the WebView UI if the page was being touched or scrolled at the time.

This is really reproducible on a Nexus One 2.2 and we have seen it on other devices.  Anyone know whats going on here?  Is there a invalidate like method that forces a redraw of the web content?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue ? I have similar case - on click I add and remove css style. Style is added but not removed on UI, until I rotate device... then everything works fine... so case happens only on first touch after url load.

Comment: @Marcin, it was a while ago and I can't quite remember how I ended up solving this.  I believe it was pretty darn ugly though. Something like:  when the style changes, set a function to run in 100ms from now that sets the div wrapping the whole page to have a random bottom padding.  That forced a relayout.  I could be wrong, since this is off of memory.  I can't check it right now, but if I revisit this, I'll come back someday and add an answer with what I ended up doing!

Comment: I agree its pretty ugly but... it really works:-) Thanks!

Comment: Same Issue here - after an append inside of an JS-function, I have to tap the element to make it visible - is there any news or a solid workaround on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I forced my webview to update, please see the code at: //WEBVIEW

```
package com.example.scroll;
// philip r brenan at gmail.com, www.appaapps.com 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyWebView(this)); 
   }
  class MyWebView extends WebView 
   {MyWebView(Context Context)
     {super(Context);
      getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");   
      new Thread()
       {public void run()
         {for(int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
           {post(new Runnable()
             {public void run()
               {loadData(content(), "text/html", "utf-8"); // Display in browser
               }
             });    
            try {Thread.sleep(5000);} catch(Exception e) {}
           }  
         }
       }.start();
     } 
    int c = 0, C = 1;
    String content() 
     {final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
      //s.append("<html id="+(C++)+"><body>"); // WEBVIEW REFRESHES CORRECTLY *************** 
      s.append("<html><body>");              // WEBVIEW DOES NOT REFRESH ******************

      s.append("<h1 id=11>1111</h1>");
      s.append("<script>location.href = '#22';</script>");
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) s.append("<p>"+c+c+c); ++c;

      s.append("<h1 id=22>2222</h1>");
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) s.append("<p>"+c+c+c); ++c;
      Log.e("AAAAAA", "content="+s.toString());
      s.append("</body></html>");
      return s.toString();
     }
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a caching issue, I had the same problem and fixed it by adding this to the setup of the webview:

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
```